# Using nested routes and nested attributes together (and optionally)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, nested-forms

Trying to do something pretty straightforward.

I have a system where we have
Clients
who have
Tasks
which have
Files and Notes

I can also create a task which is not related to one particular client.

I want to be able to create a new task, from the client screen and populate the client field (or have it populated in the background) wihtout having to select it. 
Of course, I'll need my client selector if I just create a task and then want to attach a client to it.

Hope that all makes sense

I have a nested route as follows:

```
resources :clients do
  resources :notes
  resources :tasks do
    resources :notes
    resources :task_files
  end
end
resources :tasks do
  resources :notes
  resources :task_files
end
```

And a load of stuff relating to the nested attributes etc which works.

The one thing I can't quite work out is how to use the same _form for when I'm just creating a task, and when I'm creating a task when I know the client.
e.g. clients/:id/tasks/new
vs
tasks/new

My gut feel is that if I put @project into the _form a la:

```
<%= simple_nested_form_for [@client,@task], html:{multipart: true} do |f| %>
```

then it's not going to work for tasks without clients
Whereas:

```
<%= simple_nested_form_for @task, html:{multipart: true} do |f| %>
```

Doesn't preselect the client in:

```
 <%= f.input :client_id, :collection => Client.accessible_by(current_ability, :read), :as => :select, :label => "Client" %>
```

Which is used if there is no client preselected.

Any ideas how I get that to work, maybe by being able to use the parameter @client.id in some way? 
Have tried @Client, @Client.id and :client_id with no joy.

Am sure this must be pretty simple...

To clarify:
If the client is present (i.e. known through the URL) I'd like to preselect the client and not allow it to be changed.
If the client id is not present, I'd like the user to be able to select which client it applies to (or leave it blank).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up using `selected: params[:client_id]` which left me the selector on the form but did the job.

```
<%= f.input :client_id, :collection => Client.accessible_by(current_ability, :read), selected: params[:client_id], :label => "Client", :include_blank => "" %>
```

Alternatively, can do the following (similar to answer below but different method) which might be cleaner than using the selected method in some circumstances.

```
if params.has_key?[:client_id]
....
else
....
end
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are only creating a task with this form, and never creating a client, so I would just use

```
<%= simple_form_for @task do |f| %>
```

and then include all the inputs for making a new task.
In the form for making the task, you can check whether the user instance variable of @user is defined for not. If you're at the nested route, it should be defined, and you can just a hidden field to assign the client_id.

```
<% if defined?(@user) %>
  <%= f.hidden_field, :client_id, value: @user.id %>
<% else %>
  <%= f.input :client_id, :collection => Client.accessible_by(current_ability, :read), :as => :select, :label => "Client", :value_method  => :id %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for that.
It's not a problem that I can't select the client. It's that if the context is already clear my users shouldn't need to. 
I guess I'd like something like the following:
    if client_id.present?
    f.input :client :disabled, :input_htmml (:value => client_id)
    else
    <%= f.input :client_id, :collection => Client.accessible_by(current_ability, :read), :as => :select, :label => "Client" %>
end

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up comment. I will amend my reply in order to take this extra information into account. I hope that will help.

Comment: Tried this, but perhaps it only works for '@user'. I needed it to work with @client.